# CSS link border style not working on a:visited

Tags: html, css

Problem is with link border styles, I can change it on hover, but the border on `:visited` doesn't work. Here is example of what I have:

```css
a:link {
    color: #536DFE;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: dashed 1px;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

a:hover {
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
    transform: scale(1.08);
}

a:visited {
    color: #727272;
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
}
```

The problem is the last `a:visited`, `border-bottom: solid 1px` is ignored. How can this be fixed?

Comment: You have to lead with the `width` value and define it's `style` afterwards. So: `1px solid` will work.

Comment: @somethinghere that isn't true : http://jsfiddle.net/93h05nyn/

Comment: @SexyTurnip even if it is not strictly adhered too, it is the commonly accepted standard for ordering those values and according to MDN the canonical order. Either way.

Comment: Can you show us the screen? I suspect your `:visited` would be actually the `:focus`.

Comment: I actually meant "will work" is not true. You are correct about the order of property definition.

Comment: @SexyTurnip True, if I had the chance now I'd change it to 'should' - but hey, thats why I keep it in the comments and not an answer :) Paulie_D has a really great answer, 'I did not know that' comes to mind!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`border-style` is not something you can overide on the `visited` pseudo-class

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Avisited)

> Note: For privacy reasons, browsers strictly limit the styles you can apply using an element selected by this pseudo-class: only color, background-color, **border-color, border-bottom-color, border-left-color, border-right-color, border-top-color**, outline-color, column-rule-color, fill and stroke. Note also that the alpha component will be ignored: the alpha component of the not-visited rule is used instead (except when the opacity is 0, in that case the whole color is ignored, and the one of the not-visited rule is used).

Also [**Privacy and the :visited selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector)

Comment: How on Earth could the style of a border be a privacy concern? But the rest of the properties not? Bizzare

Comment: didn't like it, but looks like true. Thanks.

Comment: details for June 2021 -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited